# Concatenate multiple rows in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have a query that produces the following results

```
NAME         WeekPattern

John Smith   
John Smith   //
John Smith   OO
Jack Jones   
Jack Jones   O
Jack Jones   //
```

Is there a way I can concatenate the WeekPattern column so the results will show like this:

```
NAME         WeekPattern

John Smith     // OO
Jack Jones     O //
```

I have tried using FOR XML PATH but couldn't get it to work, here is the query for my attempt:

```
SELECT 
p.p_surname,
p.p_forenames,
LEFT(sr.sr_weekpattern , LEN(sr.sr_weekpattern )-1) AS Weekpattern
FROM 
unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_person p ON p.p_id = sr.sr_student
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT sr.sr_weekpattern + ' '
    FROM unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr1
    INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_person p1 ON p1.p_id = sr1.sr_student

    WHERE p.p_id = p1.p_id
    FOR XML PATH('')
) pre_trimmed (Weekpattern)
GROUP BY p.p_surname, p.p_forenames, sr.sr_weekpattern;
```

I get this error when running this query:

Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your existing query, you are not referencing the correct column in the `LEFT`, you should be using:

```
SELECT 
  p.p_surname,
  p.p_forenames,
  LEFT(pre_trimmed.Weekpattern , LEN(pre_trimmed.Weekpattern)-1) AS Weekpattern
FROM unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_person p 
  ON p.p_id = sr.sr_student
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT sr1.sr_weekpattern + ' '
  FROM unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr1
  INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_person p1 
    ON p1.p_id = sr1.sr_student
  WHERE p.p_id = p1.p_id
  FOR XML PATH('')
) pre_trimmed (Weekpattern)
```

Comment: This answer works but only for half a second then it gives the error:Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @Will does the subquery work on its own if you remove the `WHERE p.p_id = p1.p_id`?

Comment: @Will the subquery doesn't have the `left` so how does that throw an error?  Does the subquery inside of the `cross apply` work on its own?

Comment: sorry, when WHERE p.p_id = p1.p_id the same error is thrown. When the subquery is run by itself it wont run because p.p_id and sr.sr_weekpattern are out of scope

Comment: @Will you have to remove that `where` clause and inside of that subquery it should be `select sr1.sr_weekpattern + ' '` as I changed in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
     Name,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ' ' + WeekPattern
          FROM TableName
          WHERE NAME = a.NAME AND WeekPattern IS NOT NULL
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS WeekPatternList
FROM TableName AS a
GROUP BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e158/2)

Comment: can you give sample records along with your question?